# Use AJAX to access JSON file objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Okay, so I'm pretty sure that my question is a simple one, but I'm a complete AJAX/JSON noob, so I need help.

I'm using $.getJSON to access a JSON file and then I want to cycle through the "messages" and display "subject", "date-time", and multiple "recipients" in list items appended to an unordered list with the class "string"

When I try the below code, nothing is happening. No list items are being appended to my unordered list. I believe I'm not narrowing down my request correctly, or I may have my JSON formatted incorrectly (although I have validated it) for the kind of thing I'm trying to accomplish.

Here's my script:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('data/conv.json',function(data){
    $('ul.string').empty();
    $.each(data.message, function(messages, message){
        var html = '<li>';                    
        html += '<span class="name">' + entry['name'] + '</span>';
        html += '<span class="timestamp">' + message['date-time'] + '</span><br class="clear"/>';                       html += '<span class="subject">' + message['subject'] + '</span>';                                      
        $('ul.string').append(html);
    });                        
});
});

 </script>
```

Here is my JSON:

```
{
"messages":{
  "message":{
     "date-time":"June 2, 2013 12:22 pm",
     "subject":"This is the message subject",
     "shopcart":"false",
     "msg-string":"001",
     "recipients":{
        "recipient-info":{
           "name":"D. Craig",
           "mbr-href":"#craig"
        },
        "recipient-info":{
           "name":"N. McCoy",
           "mbr-href":"#mccoy"
        },
        "recipient-info":{
           "name":"J. Smith",
           "mbr-href":"#smith"
        },
        "recipient-info":{
           "name":"B. Wardlaw",
           "mbr-href":"#wardlaw"
        }
     }
  },
  "message":{
     "date-time":"May 23, 2013 12:22 pm",
     "subject":"This is a great subject",
     "shopcart":"false",
     "msg-string":"002",
     "recipients":{
        "recipient-info":{
           "name":"D. Craig",
           "mbr-href":"#craig"
        },
        "recipient-info":{
           "name":"N. McCoy",
           "mbr-href":"#mccoy"
        }
     }
  },
  "message":{
     "date-time":"May 11, 2013 12:22 pm",
     "subject":"Interested in your tomatoes",
     "shopcart":"true",
     "msg-string":"004",
     "recipients":{
        "recipient-info":{
           "name":"J. Smith",
           "mbr-href":"#smith"
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

I should note that I have verified my filepath to my JSON file is correct and I do have the jQuery library loading and the unordered list created. I even used a tutorial I found online and was able to get the JSON data loading from the tutorial file, but it was a much more simple JSON file structure than what I am trying to use now.

Below is a screen shot of what my list-item should look like when it's loading. Kudos to the person who can also point me in the right direction of only loading the first two recipient's names and then display "+ {number of remaining recipients} others"

[image]

I appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the JavaScript console say?

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(data)`.

Comment: use firebug or chrome dev tools to debug your code. you can set breakpoints and run step-by-step

Comment: I'm not seeing any JS errors in Firebug.

Comment: You might also need to use `JSON.parse` so you JSON string becomes a javascript object.

Comment: a/ your json cannot work. data.messages is a dict with n times the same key. b/ `data.message` -> `data.messages`.

Comment: nota: the same goes for your `recipients`. Your first step is to get your json right.

Comment: njzk, thanks. I was afraid my JSON was not correct. However, I don't really understand what you're saying needs to be fixed.

Comment: Actually, thanks! I understand now what you were saying njzk2. I updated my JSON and was able to get everything but recipients pulling, but I'm on the right track now. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this: `$.each(data.message, function(messages, message){`

Should be this:     `$.each(data.messages.message, function(messages, message){`